# How to return lists of a paticular Content Type using PnP PowerShell

Tags: content-type, pnp-powershell

I'm using PnP Powershell for SP 2013.  I'm trying to retrieve lists that support a particular custom Content Type ("Knowledge Document").  I'm having difficulty even getting the List Content Type to print. Ultimately I wanted to use `Get-PnPList | ContentType = "My Custom Content Type"`

```
function PopulateData($web, $incldeFileSize) {
        Write-Host "Current Site " $web.url -ForegroundColor Cyan 
                  $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where{($_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary”) }

                  foreach($lib in $libs){
                    $ContentType = Get-PnPContentType -List $lib
                     write-host $ContentType
                     $libitems = (Get-PnPListItem -Web $web -List $lib -Fields "FileLeafRef","Name","Title","Author","Modified","Created","KBAbstract","KBContentAuthor","KBCategory","Publish","KBPublishDate").FieldValues

                       foreach($libitem in $libitems)
                         {

...
```

Comment: Does the solution you're looking for _have_ to use the PnP Powershell commands?  I know a great way to do this, but it uses the regular SharePoint 2013 Management Shell / `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` snap-in.  I'm not familiar with the PnP stuff, so I don't know if there is an equivalent.

Comment: I'm afraid I've been instructed to use PnP.  Thank you though!

Comment: Well, if there's any possibility of you pushing back on that and being able to use the regular SP 2013 Management Shell, you would be able to take advantage of [`SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(contentType)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.getusages), which returns a collection of [`SPContentTypeUsage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage) objects, which have properties like `Url` and `IsUrlToList`, which would be quite helpful for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps which might be helpful:

1. First fetch the lists on which content types are enabled:

   ```
   Get-PnPList | Select-Object Title, AllowContentTypes | Where-Object { $_.AllowContentTypes -Eq $true }
   ```
2. Iterate through each list and fetch their associated content types:

   ```
   Get-PnPContentType -List *ListName* -Identity *ContentTypeTitle*
   ```
3. If a list contains your content type then collect those list names.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with the following one-liner!

```
Get-PnPList -Includes ContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.ContentTypes | Where-Object Name -eq "Knowledge Document"}
```